# Onclick event triggering onload for button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a `div`, and I want to append a button created with JS to it, with JS defining the ID, `onclick`, as well as the text. Everything works fine, except for the `onclick` event triggers on page load instead of when clicked. When inspected, there isn't even a `onclick` attribute.

Here is an example:

```js
function createEditButton(num) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.onclick = myFunc();
    btn.type = "button";
    btn.innerText = "Edit";
    btn.id = "editbutton" + num;
    return btn;
}

function myFunc() {
    alert("hi");
    
}

document.getElementById('someDiv').appendChild(createEditButton(5));
```

```html
<div id="someDiv"> </div>
```

I have even tried adding the event using `addEventListener`: `btn.addEventListener("click", showEditFields(event), false);` and it results in the same. I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While registering `btn.onclick` as a click callback you are executing function instead of assigning it. you should use `addEventListener` method to register click events instead of `onclick`, the benefits of using `addEventListener` are it can easily register multiple callback while if suppose you are assigning 'onclick' value twice the first value will get replaced.

And to pass value to function you can use `bind` function. `bind` will create new function with given context and arguments bound to it. or you can simply create a wrapper function which will execute the call back function with given arguments.

**[Bind: MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)**

See the below example.

```js
function createEditButton(num) {
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.addEventListener('click', myFunc);

  // Using Bind to pass value
  btn.addEventListener('click', myFuncWithVal.bind(btn, num));


  // Uaing Wrapper function to pass value
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert('wrapper function');
    myFuncWithVal(num);
  });

  btn.type = "button";
  btn.innerText = "Edit";
  btn.id = "editbutton" + num;
  return btn;
}

function myFunc() {
  alert("hi");
}


function myFuncWithVal(val) {
  alert(val);
}

document.getElementById('someDiv').appendChild(createEditButton(5));
```

```html
<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's b/c you are calling the function instead of referencing it:

```
btn.onclick = myFunc(); /* <-- remove parens */

btn.onclick = myFunc;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will accept your answer when I can.

Comment: So then what if my function has parameters?

Comment: When function has parameter you must have a wrapper function that calls that function with specific parameters.

Comment: Doesn't matter. All you are doing here is referring to the (name of) the function that you intend to handle the event in question. Removing the parens is exactly what you want (b/c) the parens make this a function call (thus assigning the result of that call as your handler) -- this will not affect any params passed to the handler.

Comment: True but then those params that you need would be undefined or equal to mouseeventargs.

Comment: There were no params being passed in the original example, seems like a different question. This answer is correct. As is yours.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function createEditButton(num) {
 var btn = document.createElement("button");
 btn.onclick = myFunc;
 btn.type = "button";
 btn.innerText = "Edit";
 btn.id = "editbutton" + num;
 return btn;
}

function myFunc() {
    alert("hi");
    
}

document.getElementById('someDiv').appendChild(createEditButton(5));
```

```html
<div id="someDiv"> </div>
```

Comment: The problem was that you actually called that function by creating button. What you want to do is just delegate that function so setting onclick= myFunc;